# WPF:C#: The name "Interaction or eventtrigger or contolstroyboardaction" does not exist in the namespace " "

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

this is my code, I have searched for all the solutions or answers given in stackoverflow, but didn't help me. 
Previously when this error occurred, I just build it and will start working, but every time its giving me the same error for different parts. I have searched all the possible solution but did not help me.

```
<Window 
   xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
   xmlns:x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
   xmlns:d = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
   xmlns:mc = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
   xmlns:local = "clr-namespace:WPFBehaviors" 
   xmlns:i = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
   xmlns:ei = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
   x:Class = "WPFBehaviors.MainWindow" 
   mc:Ignorable = "d" Title = "MainWindow" Height = "350" Width = "604">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="Storyboard1" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="301.524" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="2.909" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty= "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="-0.485" />
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="0" />
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="button">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Play" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="button1">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Stop" />
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="Stop" />
            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}" />
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFAAAAC5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50.901" Margin="49.324, 70.922,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="73.684" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        </Ellipse>
        <Button x:Name = "button" Content = "Play" HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Height = "24.238"
         Margin = "63.867,0,0,92.953" VerticalAlignment = "Bottom" Width = "74.654">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName = "Click">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard = "{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>

        <Button x:Name = "button1" Content = "Stop" HorizontalAlignment = "Left" Height = "24.239"
         Margin = "160.82,0,0,93.922" VerticalAlignment = "Bottom" Width = "75.138">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName = "Click">
                    <ei:ControlStoryboardAction ControlStoryboardOption = "Stop"
                  Storyboard = "{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Provide some more details about where this error occurs in the provided code and remove items from code that are not applicable to the question.
Your question is tagged C#. Do you have C# code as well?

Comment: Does this link help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/327abb86-d579-470d-b1fe-f2cfcd170336/what-assembly-is-xmlnsihttpschemasmicrosoftcomexpression2010interactivity-in?forum=wpf ?

Comment: Gerard Sexton, thank you for you reply,

Comment: but there is no code in C#, all done in wpf, and error appears in <i:...>,<ei:....> tags.

Answer (score 0):

For all projects using this XAML you can check references toward
**Microsoft.Expression.Interactions** and **System.Windows.Interactivity** (be carefull with framework versions when adding references!)